# I can't make a dropdown menu to generate a second level submenu

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, menu, submenu

There is no list of `<li>`inside another since I just want the class "producto" to generate the submenu. I can make the item 'producto' to have a background when I hover it so I think the specification is fine. 
I want a dropdown submenu nested to the class "producto" since I don't know why the rule ".product:hover..." is not working. I want to use this menu for a larger website, that's why I don't use `<li>` wrapped to `<a>` tags (it disorganizes the structure when I use it on the larger website).

```css
.menu1 {
 position:relative;
 background: rgba(110,50,3,0.2);
    
 
}


.menu1 a {
 background:#6f2;
 display:col;
 float:left;
 color: #fff;
 height: 10px;
 text-decoration: none;
 padding-right:60px;
 padding-left:110px;
 padding-top:10px;
 padding-bottom:40px;
    margin-top:0px;
 margin-bottom:0px;
 margin-left:0px;
 margin-right:0px;
  
}


.menu1 ul li{
 
 position:absolute;
 left:290px;
 top:-10px;
    display:none;
 color: #f23;
 width: 100px;
 padding-top:90px;
 padding-left:30px;
 padding-right:60px;
 padding-bottom:10px;
 margin-top:0px;
 margin-bottom:0px;
 list-style-type:none;
 
}

.producto {
 position:relative;
 display:col;
 background:rgba(250,50,3,0.3);
}
.producto:hover  ul li   {
 background: rgba(250,50,3,0.3);
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="prueba2.css">

</head>
<body>
<nav class="menu1">
   
       <a href="#">Inicio<img src="flechita.png"></a>
       <a href="#">Nosotros<img src="flechita.png"></a>
          <a href="#" class="producto">Productos / Licenciamientos<img src="flechita.png"></a>    
     <ul>
      <li>Laptops</li>
      <li>Desktop</li>
     </ul>    
     <a href="">Hardware<img src="flechita.png"></a>
     <a href="">Contacto<img src="flechita.png"></a>
    
</nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Since the list items you want to show after the hover are not inside the .producto area the css rule '.producto:hover ul li' will not work.

Comment: The `<ul>` block is next to the class "producto" , doesn't that mean is inside it?.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

HTML:

```
<ul id='nlist'>
        <li><a href='#' class='home'>Home</a></li>
        <li><a href='#' class='about'>About</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropbtn">Links</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-content">
                  <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
                </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href='#' class='volunteer'>Volunteer</a></li>
        <li><a href='#' class='contact'>Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href='#' class='calender'>Calender</a></li>
    </ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul {

}

.dropdown{
  position:relative;
}
li a, .dropbtn {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    left:-9999px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
    left:0px;
}

ul {
  background-color: #a2ded0;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    border: 0px;
    vertical-align: middle; 
}

ul#nlist {
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

ul#nlist li {
    display: inline;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/p9Lea8g4/7/